# how can i generate an event in kivy, like an on_touch_down or on_touch_up event

Tags: python, events, kivy

Is it possible to generate an event in kivy so that an on_touch_up or on_touch_down function can be called without the user touching the screen?

Answer (score 1):

First see the note in the documentation for [Motion Event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html?highlight=motionevent#module-kivy.input.motionevent):

> You never create the MotionEvent yourself: this is the role of the
>   providers.

Having said that, You can create and dispatch a minimal event like this:

```
class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def mydispatchAnEvent(self):
        touch = MouseMotionEvent(None, 123, (123, 456))  # args are device, id, spos
        touch.button = 'left'
        touch.pos = (321, 654)
        self.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch)
```

The class (in this case `MyBoxLayout`) must be an `EventDispatcher`. Calling `mydispatchAnEvent()` will dispatch a minimal event to all the children of `MyBoxLayout`.

Comment: can you please tell me where you got MouseMotionEvent() from.

Comment: okay, MouseMotionEvent is a class that inherits from the abstract class MotionEvent.

Answer (score 0):

With this code I can generate the touch_down event but for some reason it does not work with touch_up. if someone knows the answer it will be appreciated.

To switch a tab it needs both touch_down and touch_up.

```
enter code here

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.input.providers.mouse import MouseMotionEvent

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTabs:
        id: android_tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)


<Tab>:

    MDLabel:
        id: label
        text: "Tab 0"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.root.ids.android_tabs.add_widget(Tab(title=f"Tab {i}"))
        Window.bind(on_motion=self.on_motion)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dispatchTouchDown, 2)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dispatchTouchUp, 2.5)

    def on_motion(self, obj, tevent, touch):
        print (tevent, touch.sx*Window.width, touch.sy*Window.height)


    def on_tab_switch(
        self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        instance_tab.ids.label.text = tab_text

    def dispatchTouchDown(self, *args):
        # create and dispatch a fake event
        touch = MouseMotionEvent(None, 0, (0, 0))  # args are device, id, spos
        touch.button = 'left'
        touch.pos = (130, 570)
        touch.x = touch.px = touch.ox = 130
        touch.y = touch.py = touch.oy = 570
        Window.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch)
        #This works

    def dispatchTouchUp(self, *args):
        # create and dispatch a fake event
        touch = MouseMotionEvent(None, 0, (0, 0))  # args are device, id, spos
        touch.button = 'left'
        touch.pos = (130, 570)
        touch.x = touch.px = touch.ox = 130
        touch.y = touch.py = touch.oy = 570
        Window.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch)
        #This does not work

Example().run()
```